# Multiplying a column based on another column value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to multiply a column of values by 100 based on another column value. I get an error.

```
Sub macro1()
Dim f As Range

Set f = Range("B2:B5").Value

For i = 2 To 100000
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        If .Range("A" & i).Value = "Pavel" Then
            .Range("B" & i).Value = f * 100
Next i
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't get it, You are trying to multiply 4 numbers by 100 and get the result?  Are you adding the 4 numbers up before multiplying or are you multiplying each by 100 then adding.

Comment: To provide some clarification, please add an example input and an expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start a new line after the `then` in your IF statement, then you must end the block with `End if` (let's ignore the line continuation character for now) -- else the syntax is not valid.

So either do:

```
If 1 > 0 then
     Msgbox("True!")
End if
```

Or:

```
If 1 > 0 then Msgbox("True!")
```

But don't start a new line after `then`, and not include the `End if`.

Also, it's better to put `Option Explicit` before your code and your `f` variable seems unused -- but that wasn't your question.

Comment: that is one problem, yes, but also the OP is trying to multiply an array by 100 which also will error with typemismatch.

Answer (score 0):

So... Whenever you have `For` you need `Next`. For `If` there is a need of `End If`, unless it is not on the same line. For `With` there is an `End With` needed.

Thus, in general, just to get you started somewhere, this works somehow:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro()
    Dim f As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set f = Range("B2:B5")

    For i = 2 To 100000
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            If .Range("A" & i).Value = "Pavel" Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = .Range("B" & i) * 100
            End If
        End With
    Next i    
End Sub
```

Take a look at the `Option Explicit` at the top of the code, it is really important and brings your code one level up - [MSDN Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement).